# Chrome cast connecting and showing title and description but not playing video and not displying presentDefaultExpandedMediaControls

Tags: ios, chromecast

Please give me some idea about the expandedMedia. I implemented as in the documentation like, 
`[GCKCastContext sharedInstance].useDefaultExpandedMediaControls = YES;`

It says : **no visible @interface for GCKCastContext**

Please give me any solution for this.

Thank You!

Comment: I suggest you look at the sample app on our github repo: https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-ios

Comment: Thank you for the information :) But I checked that one there lots of things implemented. I checked the documentation provided by the google and implement that one in the link here, https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-ios/#8          But this is not working and says not visible @interface  for GCKCastContext

Comment: Thanks @AliNaddaf  **Finally solved** : With updating cocoapods file as,  ` pod 'google-cast-sdk', '~> 3.1.1' ` where GCKUIExpandedMediaControlsViewController is included after that  useDefaultExpandedMediaControls is working.